# bipartite minimum edges

Tags: graph-theory, bipartite

I looking for a simple algorithm getting the minimum weighted edge among the edges for a bipartite graph. I searched and I all could know it means the cover edge of a bipartite in other words if we have bipartite graph and each edge has a number weight how to get the smallest number among them

[image: example]

Comment: I assume that you are asking for the minimum weighted vertex cover of the bipartite graph?

Comment: no its not vertex its edge I found a lot of algorithms about weighted vertex this is not what I need

Comment: If your question is just "minimum weighted edge among the edges for a bipartite graph", then just iterate the edges of the graph and take the smallest. But this seems like I'm not understanding your question - can you give an example?

Answer (score 0):

The way this question is posed makes it very unclear. One of the interpretations I got from it was: "Given a weighted bipartite graph G, how do I obtain the minimum edge cover of G ?". If that is the case, then the [Hungarian algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm) (see http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FindEdgeCover.html also) solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need the Hungarian algorithm.
Click [here](http://math.mit.edu/~goemans/18433S09/matching-notes.pdf)
to get lecture notes.

Before processing, you should have a cost matrix, where each entry is the edge cost
from node A to node B. The matching steps as follows:

---

1. Substract the smallest entry in each row
2. Substract the smallest entry in each column
3. Draw lines through appropriate rows and columns, so that
    all the zero entries of the cost matrix are covered and the 
    minimum numver of such lines is used
4. Test for optimally: 
   (1) if the minimum number of covering lines is n, an optimal assignment is possible and we are finished. (2) if the ninimum number of covering lines is less than n, an optimal assignment of zeros is not yet possible. GOTO step 5.
5. Determine the smallest entry not covered by any line. Substract the entry from each uncovered row, and then add it to each covered column. Return to step 3.

---

The  algorithm above is based on a mathematic therorem that

- If a number is added to or substracted from all of the entries of any one row or column of a cost matrix, then an optimal assgnment for the resulting cost matrix is also an optimal assgnment for the original cost matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Even better than the Hungarian Algorithm as suggested in the other answers, is the Jonker-Volgenant ([LAPJV](http://rd.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF02278710)) algorithm.

Take a look at this GitHub repository aptly named [Bipartite Solver](https://github.com/dberm22/Bipartite-Solver), which is basically a tutorial on how to implement LAPJV in code, complete with a runnable graphical sample.

It's crazy fast, able to do 1000 to 1000 in under a second.

Also included in the library is greedy search, which is even faster, but does not guarantee optimality.

The library also has some [executables](https://github.com/dberm22/Bipartite-Solver/tree/master/bin) if you wish to try out the algorithms without having to build it from source.